# Virtual host doesn't work on WAMP and virtual host url causes to download a file in browser

Tags: apache, wamp, virtualhost, wampserver

I have a strange problem in accessing to virtual host in `WAMP`.

I have defined my virtual host (it calls `mvc.dev`) by defining in `server configuration` page in `wampserver`. Steps are exact that I have explained in the following:

1- first, going to server configuration page and select `Add a virtual host`

[image]

2- As `index.php` in my project is in `C:\wamp64\www\mvcdev\public path`, so I fill out related fields for my virtual host and then start to creation of virtual host.

[image]

3- It is created correctly and wamp server wants to restart DNS manually. I restarted it from wamp server menu like this:

[image]

4- After restarting, I check localhost page. It shows that `mvc.dev` is created correctly without any problem

[image]

5- And the problem occurs here, when I click on mvc.dev or type it in address bar of browser to access my virtual host, it causes to download a file instead of loading index.php file. I'm so frustrated about this issue and I don't know how can I solve this. Why does it cause to download hex file instead of executing URL?

[image]

This file is a hex file and every time that I put `mvc.dev` in url, it will start to download this file

[image]

For your information, I have  also tested it by defining virtual host manually. I put related codes in `httpd-vhosts.conf` and then define mvc.dev in `host` and then `restart DNS`, but the result is the same with thing that I have explained before and I can not access to my virtual host at all. You can see it in the following:

configuration in `host` file:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1   mvc.dev
::1 mvc.dev
```

configuration of `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mvc.dev
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/mvcdev/public
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/mvcdev/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Note: I also checked this one by one but I couldn't solve my problem:
[project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server)

The `.htaccess` file is

```
# Remove the question mark from the request but maintain the query string
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

The code in `index.php` is

```
echo 'Request URL is: '.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; 
//require '../core/Router.php'; 
require "../vendor/autoload.php"; 
$router = new Core\Router(); 
$router->add('/','HomeController@index');
```

Comment: I see you have a `.htaccess` file in the DocumentRoot folder! What is in this `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You should really not give `Require all granted` to your localhost Virtual Host

Comment: This is for accepting query string without typing index.php:
# Remove the question mark from the request but maintain the query string
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: One thing, I check it without .htaccess file, but the result is the same

Comment: Require part is added by wamp (when I create it like something that I have explained above)

Comment: In that case, what is the code in the `.php` file

Comment: it has only several lines of codes only for testing a class:
echo 'Request URL is: '.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

//require '../core/Router.php';
require "../vendor/autoload.php";

$router = new Core\Router();

$router->add('/','HomeController@index');

Comment: Try using a simple `<?php echo 'hello'; ?>` and see if that works

Comment: I tested it. The result is the same before. Do you need to extra information? if you want, I can add them in the end of my question

Comment: Does that PHP code have a `<?php` on the first line?

Comment: yes, of course, I also check this by only <?php echo 'hello'; ?> but it didn't work at all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found out that Chrome requires any *.dev to be access via HTTPS and any chromium base browser will negate localhost access to it. [Check this link](https://superuser.com/questions/1284098/virtual-host-domains-other-than-local-not-working-in-chrome)

Change the website extension to something else. That worked for me. For example instead of `example.com` use `example.tst`.

Comment: worked for me in Mozilla firefox Thanks a tone @raphie